# Como puedo solucionar este error? (Error: para ver los datos del datagriview tengo que hacer click encima de la celda o grilla)

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber si alguien me ayuda a resolver este error ya que he buscado informacion detallada en internet y no he encontrado nada relacionado.

**Imagen del error que me aparece:** "El error que da es que para ver los registros del datagriview tengo que hacer click encima de cada celda"

[image: Error]

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando para llenar el datagriview:

```
public class ClsCDCliente
    {
        public List<ClsCliente> Listar()
        {
            List<ClsCliente> Lista = new List<ClsCliente>();
            using (SqlConnection oConexion = new SqlConnection(ClsConexion.Cadena))
            {
                try
                {
                    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                    query.AppendLine("select IDCliente, Documento, Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Correo, Telefono, Estado from Cliente");
                    
                    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), oConexion);
                    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    oConexion.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader DR = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (DR.Read())
                        {
                            Lista.Add(new ClsCliente()
                            {
                                IDCliente = Convert.ToInt32(DR["IDCliente"]),
                                Documento = DR["Documento"].ToString(),
                                Nombre = DR["Nombre"].ToString(),
                                Apellido = DR["Apellido"].ToString(),
                                Direccion = DR["Direccion"].ToString(),
                                Correo = DR["Correo"].ToString(),
                                Telefono = DR["Telefono"].ToString(),
                                Estado = Convert.ToBoolean(DR["Estado"]),
                                
                            });
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Lista = new List<ClsCliente>();
                }
            }
            return Lista;
        }


//Mostrar todos los usuarios

            List<ClsCliente> Lista = new ClsCNCliente().Listar();

            foreach (ClsCliente item in Lista)
            {
                DGVData.Rows.Add(new object[] {"",item.IDCliente, item.Documento, item.Nombre, item.Apellido, item.Direccion, item.Correo,item.Telefono,
            
            item.Estado == true ? 1 : 0,
             item.Estado == true ? "Activo" : "No activo",
             ((ClsOpcionCombo)CBEstado.SelectedItem).Texto.ToString(),

            });
```

Comment: No será que tienes el color de la letra en blanco?

Comment: No, he verificado todo eso y ese no es el caso. Gracias

Comment: No hay absolutamente nada en el codigo que muestras, que nos de un indicio de que tipo de app es.. es winform, es wpf? como se construye esa grilla? que tipo de grilla es? tu escenerio, asi como esta, es irreproducible para nosotros. Seguro nadie cambia los colores? todas las celdas se ven? probaste con otra grilla nueva sin formato a ver que pasa? y que bueno que solucionaste lo del dbnull, sin decirnos nada ;)

Comment: Buenas, he cambiado el datagriview y tampoco se ha solucionado el error, con respecto a lo que mencionas del dbnull tampoco lo he solucionado, estoy revisando el codigo para ver lo que es. Gracias

Comment: Lo del dbNull es porque si un dato es null en la BD y lo tratas de convertir a string te marca ese error, Osea si tienes DR["Documento"].toString() y Documento es null te va a marcar error lo que puedes hacer es Documento = DR["Documento"] == DBNull.Value ? null : DR["Documento"].ToString(). Esto con todos los campos que puedan ser null en la bd